# How to zoom on a photo

Tags: qfield

We have set up a little form with a few attributes and a photo.
Once the photo is saved, it is not possible to reopen it and to zoom in the picture.
Any tricks?

Answer (score 1):

There is no subsequent photonedit functionality embedded in QField (yet).

After photo taken in QField, you need to find your photo in phone's gallery - edit it there - and select the new* image in QField's attribute form.

* As far as I know, editors usually don't save the changes to the same image. They always create a new one.